# Forgot Amazon EC2 instance [windows 2008 server] password.

Tags: amazon-ec2

I cannot retrieve the password for my EC2 instance running  Windows 2008 server. I want this particular instance and my get password does not work. 
Any work around how I can retrieve the password.

Comment: I cannot log into my instance, is there a way to duplicate the EC2 instance.

Comment: [http://aws.amazon.com/en/contact-us/](http://aws.amazon.com/en/contact-us/)

Comment: Contacting tech support wont matter. Amazon does not have visibility on your password. You can create a volume from a snapshot and attach it to a new instance.

Comment: Just in case anybody gets here in the future... Here's an answer for you: http://serverfault.com/questions/370283/ec2-windows-password-recover

Answer (score 3):

Your server is launched from an AMI most probably that is the reason you cannot retrieve your password. It has happened to me in past. In short what you have to do is create an image of the existing instance and then launch a new instance using that image.

- create a snapshot with ec2-create-snapshot
- attach the snapshot to a new instance.